# jQuery normally cached when loaded from Google CDN?

Tags: jquery, caching, cdn

I know one of the benefits of linking jQuery from Google's CDN is that as other sites do the same, the file may be cached on the user's computer and not have to be downloaded again. How often will this be the case?

If I link to the latest version of jQuery for a particular site im unlikely to bother going back and changing the link each time a new version is out.

Thanks

Comment: There's some stats about (which I can't find ATM) that made me question whether using the Google CDN was worthwhile. 1. There are so many versions of jquery in use. 2. How long do items stay in the cache. Will see if I can find the article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't be bothered changing those JQuery versions, then its not likely that the thousands of other sites using Google's CDN for JQuery will go and change all their back versions as soon as a new version is out.

What i'm trying to get at is that its still a valid benefit of using the CDN because it is still significantly more likely a new user will have the version of JQuery you are using on your site from the CDN, than it is they will have the one they would have to download from your server.

Comment: I see what your saying, are there any stats available on how often it will be cached though? I prefer working with jQuery when writing javascript. If im only doing simple things though it can be hard to justify loading an entire library. There is a trade off between loading times (particularly on mobile) and speed of development. Having some rough stats would help to inform my decision. Thanks

Comment: Well I wouldn't use JQuery if you're doing something simple. It's not going to cache your code for you so the user will still have to download any javascript you write, so its simple then there would be no justification to it you are right. Its not really a "I'm going to use JQuery because i can use Googles CDN" but rather a "I'm using JQuery so I will load it off Googles CDN". The only real stats I can find about the potential caching is in this article: http://encosia.com/6953-reasons-why-i-still-let-google-host-jquery-for-me/

Comment: Also using my limited knowledge of HTTP Headers, the response of the JQuery from google cdn has this line: max-age: 31536000, which i think means that it will be cached for a maximum of 31536000 seconds (or 365 days)

Comment: Its more a case of I find the jQuery cross browser consistency, extensive plugins, and general syntax easier to work with. Thanks